# How do I assign value to uint32_t key[4]

Tags: c++

How do I assign value to `uint32_t key[4]`

I initially have this `uint32_t iv[2] = {0xFFFFFFDD};`

Then at my 2nd run.. I need assign a new value.. lets assume the new value is

```
10273348653513887325 (decimal) but recorded as string for now.

string value = "10273348653513887325";
```

But I want change the value of `iv` from `0xFFFFFFDD` (hexadecimal) to `10273348653513887325` (decimal)

How do I do it?

Comment: what do you mean? you want to convert that string to an int?

Comment: In order to store into a `uint32_t[4]`, you need to first have a `uint32_t[4]`. Unless I'm misreading your question, you only have a `uint32_t[2]`.

Comment: You initially state: "How do i assign value to uint32_t key[4] I initially have this How do i assign value to uint32_t iv[2] = {0xFFFFFFDD};" but then it was modified to fix formatting.  Due to its ambiguity, the editor may have gotten it incorrect.  In any case, the question is still a bit vague.  Could you please clarify the question more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  10273348653513887325 as a decimal will not fit into a uint32_t.  You can pretend that iv is a 64 bit value thus:

```
uint64_t* piv = (uint64_t*)&iv[0];
*piv = decValue; // where dec value is the decimal conversion of the string
```

but after you've done that, what you'll really have are two 32 bit values that each have a portion of the value you're trying to store.  Just because that's not awkward enough, the endianness of the architecture you're using comes into play.  So don't do that.

Another alternative is to use an anonymous union of 2 32bit values and one 64 bit value.

It might merit pointing out that the assignment

```
uint32_t iv[2] = {0xFFFFFFDD };
```

results in the first element in iv having that value, and the second containing 0.  Is that what you meant?

As pointed out by @hvd, there's some lack of clarity about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The assignment will not result in every element having that value. It sets iv[0] = 0xffffffdd and iv[1] = 0.

Comment: so it does, my bad, will edit to reflect such.  Thanks for pointing that out